Why can a readonly tuple in function parameters not be inferred in TypeScript?
While experimenting around with readonly function parameters, I stumbled across some strange behaviour.
type Test1 = Parameters<(...args: [string] | [number]) => void>;
// Test1 is [string] | [number] as expected

type Test2 = Parameters<(...args: Readonly<[string] | [number]>) => void>;
// Test2 is never

While there is not really a point in using readonly tuples for spread function parameters, so this problem can be solved easily, I would still like to understand what is causing this.
Boiling it down to a simple example:
type Test3 = ((...args: Readonly<[string] | [number]>) => void) extends (...args: infer P) => any ? true : false;
// Test3 is false

type Test4 = ((...args: Readonly<[string] | [number]>) => void) extends (...args: any) => any ? true : false;
// Test4 is true

So far I was under the assumption that infer P would be equivalent to any, except that it stores the inferred type in P. That does not seem to be the case. How can this behaviour be explained?

This is considered a bug in TypeScript, as reported at microsoft/TypeScript#45276. Looks like unions of readonly tuples in rest parameter position don't properly infer in conditional types. Presumably it's not the sort of thing people tend to do (having a readonly list of function parameters is strange) so it's not too surprising that a bug around that behavior could persist.
Anyway, it's been listed in the Backlog milestone so anyone interested in seeing this fixed might want to work on it themselves.
